# Selenium random resolution from text file

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is possible to set random resolution to FireFox using text file or some other method?
I tried:

```
browser.set_window_size(random.choice(uas))
```

and got error:
browser.set_window_size(random.choice(uas))
TypeError: set_window_size() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

browser.set_window_size REQUIRES **2** arguments, width and height

Therefore if you want to use random.choice to set the window size, do :

```
random_sequence = [520,1300,650,320]
browser.set_window_size(random.choice(a), random.choice(a)) 
#                Argument above is width, argument above is height.
```

As you can see `browser.set_window_size(500, 1000)` where 500 is width and 1000 is height. That's why it requires ***2*** args.
We can read that number from a text file or a random sequence like in the example above.

Please refer to the documentation for more information.***[Click HERE](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html?highlight=window_size#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_window_size)***